# conditional binary operator expected , what is the problem? (shell)

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to write a shell-script that would **print** all the **arguments** passed to the script.
The condition is, the argument has to either be an **uneven number** or **smaller than 23**

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i<$#; i++ ));
do
        if [[ $i % 2 -ne 0 ]] || [[ $i -lt 23 ]];
        then
                echo $i
        fi
done
```

When I try to Run this script as followed `sh myScript.sh 1 3 4 6 24 23 22`
My expected output would be  `1 , 3 , 4 , 6 , 22 , 23`

**However** I get the following Error:

```
myScript.sh: line 4: conditional binary operator expected
myScript.sh: line 4: syntax error near `%'
myScript.sh: line 4: `        if [[ $i % 2 -ne 0 ]] || [[ $i -lt 23 ]];'
```

Can anyone help me understand what the error means?

Thank you!

Comment: `%` is not an operator in [[...]]. Use `if ((i % 2 != 0 || i < 23))`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but I get a different Error now: ```myScript.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
myScript.sh: line 5: `        then'
```

Comment: This is bash code so use `bash myScript.sh 1 3 ...`

Comment: Most likely you forgot a semicolon. `if ((i % 2 != 0 || i < 23)); then echo $i; fi` should work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes exactly !

Comment: @TedLyngmo my bad! that was just an example of mine to show what i meant, sorry !

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I've done exactly as you wrote... :( Here is what I had: 
```for (( i=0; i<$#; i++ ));
do
        if ((i % 2 != 0)) || ((i < 23);
        then
          echo $i;
        fi
done
```
Error: ```line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then' ```

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the suggestion. What does it change exactly ? when do you use what?

Comment: You are missing a `)`. Just copy and paste what I wrote: `if ((i % 2 != 0 || i < 23)); then echo $i; fi`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin omg, this is embarassing xD . Thank you so much for your patience and effort to help, I really appreciate it :) . everything works now!!

Comment: Depending on your particular `sh` implementation, you might get `[[: not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
do
    if (( var%2 || var<23 ))       # arithmetic expansion
    then
        echo $var
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
1
3
4
6
23
22
```

Comment: It should be checking if `argv[i]` (not `i`)  is odd or less than 23.

Comment: @chepner Ok, I must have read his code wrong.... Oh yeah, fixed it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your Help! This works fine, and you showed me something new "Arithmetic Expansion".